# SQL Server dynamically change WHERE clause in a SELECT based on returned data

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I'm mainly a presentation/logic tier developer and don't mess around with SQL all that much but I have a problem and am wondering if it's impossible within SQL as it's not a full programming language.

- I have a field ContactID which has an CompanyID attached to it
- In another table, the CompanyID is attached to CompanyName
- I am trying to create a SELECT statement that returns ONE CONTACT ID and in a seperate column, an aggregate of all the Companies attached to this contact (by name).

E.G

```
ContactID - CompanyID - CompanyName
***********************************
1           001         Lol
1           002         Haha
1           003         Funny
2           002         Haha
2           004         Lmao
```

I want to return

```
ContactID - Companies
*********************
1           Lol, Haha, Funny
2           Haha, Lmao
```

I have found the logic to do so with ONE ContactID at a time:

```
SELECT x.ContactID, substring(
  (
        SELECT ', '+y.CompanyName AS [text()]
        FROM TblContactCompany x INNER JOIN TblCompany y ON x.CompanyID = y.CompanyID WHERE x.ContactID = 13963
        For XML PATH (''), root('MyString'), type 
        ).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') 
        , 3, 1000) 
        [OrgNames] from TblContact x WHERE x.ContactID = 13963
```

As you can see here, I am hardcoding in the ContactID 13963, which is neccessary to only return the companies this individual is linked to.

The issue is when I want to return this aggregate information PER ROW on a much bigger scale SELECT (on a whole table full of ContactID's).

I want to have `x.ContactID = (this.ContactID)` but I can't figure out how!

Failing this, could I run one statement to return a list of ContactID's, then in the same StoredProc run another statement that LOOPS through this list of ContactID's (essentially performing the second statement x times where x = no. of ContactID's)?

Any help *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ct.ContactID,
       stuff((SELECT ', ' + co.CompanyName AS [text()]
                  FROM TblContactCompany cc INNER JOIN
                       TblCompany co
                       ON cc.CompanyID = co.CompanyID
                  WHERE cc.ContactID = ct.ContactId
                  For XML PATH (''), root('MyString'), type 
             ).value('/MyString[1]', 'varchar(max)'),
             1, 2, '')
        [OrgNames]
from TblContact ct;
```

Note the `where` clause on the inner subquery.

I also made two other changes:

1. I changed the table aliases to better represent the table names.  This makes queries easier to understand.  (Plus, the aliases had to be changed because you were using `x` in the outer query and the inner query.)
2. I replaced the `substring()` with `stuff()`, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: I think I love you - this is bloody awesome!

Works really nicely and has made me really interested in learning more complicated SQL!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table variable to store the required `x.ContactID` and in your main query in the `WHERE` clause use `IN` clause like below

```
WHERE
...
x.ContactID IN (SELECT ContactID FROM @YourTableVariable)
```

Comment: I think I have implemented this like you have stated however now every row shows the same Column which seems to include all the company names possibly across the whole table!

Answer (score 1):

I guess all you need to do is to use unique table identifiers in your subquery and join the table in subquery with outer table x:

```
SELECT x.ContactID, substring(
  (
        SELECT ', '+z.CompanyName AS [text()]
        FROM TblContactCompany y, TblCompany z WHERE y.CompanyID = z.CompanyID AND y.ContactId = x.ContactId
        For XML PATH (''), root('MyString'), type 
        ).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)')
        , 3, 1000) 
        [OrgNames] from TblContact x
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop or you will get performance problems (row by agonising row RBAR). Instead do set based queries.

This is untested but should give you an idea of how it may work:

```
SELECT 
    x.ContactID, 
    substring(
        (SELECT ', '+y.CompanyName AS [text()]
        FROM TblContactCompany y
        WHERE x.CompanyID = y.CompanyID 
        For XML PATH (''), root('MyString'), type).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)') 
    , 3, 1000) 
    [OrgNames] 
FROM TblContact x
```

And I have a feeling you can use CONCAT instead of substring